# How to get all keys from dictionary that specified values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have dict like this:

```
some_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
```

How to get keys that have values 2, like this:

```
some_dict.search_keys(2)
```

This is example. Assume some_dict is has many thousands or more keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[key for key, value in some_dict.items() if value == 2]
```

This uses a list comprehension to iterate through the pairs of `(key, value)` items, selecting those keys whose value equals 2.

Note that this requires a linear search through the dictionary, so it is *O(n)*. If this performance is not acceptable, you will probably need to create and maintain another data structure that indexes your dictionary by value.

Comment: An example of this answer's last sentence: `reversed_dict = collections.defaultdict(list);for k, v in some_dict.items(): reversed_dict[v].append(k)`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use dictionary comprehension, if you want result to be dictionary

```
{ x:y for x,y in some_dict.items() if y == 2}
```

output:

```
{'c': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to produce found key values, one by one, instead of returning all of them at once.

The function `search_keys` returns generator

```
def search_keys(in_dict, query_val):
    return (key for key, val in in_dict.iteritems() if val == query_val)

# get keys, one by one
for found_key in search_keys(some_dict, 2):
    print(found_key)
```